# Initial ping failure in Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, ping, packet-tracer, icmp

In Packet Tracer 7.0:

After directly connecting two switches or a router and switch, pinging the neighboring device always fails on the first one or 2 attempts (i.e. only 4/5 or 3/5 ping attempts are successful.)

[image: screenshot-icmp]

Is this an artifact of the PT simulation or is this an expected behavior on a "new" network whose hosts have never communicated with the switch before (ARP resolution?)

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Copy the text, paste it into your question, and use the Preformatted text feature (`{}`) on it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This actually happens in the real world, too. On ethernet, and other protocols that use MAC addresses, it is due to ARP. You will drop one or two initial pings. It can happen, too, with frame relay, depending on how you have it configured.